# How to use Left(), Right(), Mid(), and Len() functions in UWP?

Tags: .net, vb.net, uwp

I'm porting over a .vb source file from a VB.NET Windows forms project into my new VB UWP project, and the `Left()`, `Right()`, `Mid()`, and `Len()` functions are not defined.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use these legacy VB6 functions instead of [`String.Substring()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring) and [`String.Length`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.length)?

Comment: Yes, I would get in the habit of eliminating anything from `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace as you can.  There are a few nice outliers, but for string operations your code base will be better for it.

Comment: Is there a reason why one would not want to use perfectly fuctional methods and functions? And is there a reason why there is no numericupdown in UWP?

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli Yes, there is. Actually, this is a very good example of why you shouldn't be using them. As you can see, they're not supported here, and they're not supported in .NET core as well (AFAIK). You should stick with methods that will stay consistent everywhere in the .NET world.

Comment: Perhaps I made a mistake by posting my first comment in a form of a question. I might have got tricked by the OP's reputation and assumed that he must be aware of `.Substring()` and `.Length`. He might not be aware of them and I shouldn't have posted it as a question, I apologize for that. I did add links to the documentation though, just in case.

Comment: you need to be more specific about your errors , maybe post some screenshots and steps to reproduce.

Comment: @DougNull, actually, using `String.Length` over `Len` menas fewer keystrokes. For `Len`, you have to type all three letters while, for `Length`, Intellisense selects it by default as soo as you type the "L". Also, the fact that you call `Length` on a `String` reference while `Len` is unqualified doesn't make it any less efficient because you still have to pass that same reference to `Len` as an argument. Your argument is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

<s>You can include a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` to resolve these, and then import the namespace.</s>

The VisualBasic string methods you want are not currently supported in `UWP`, despite having [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt185497.aspx):

> Note that .NET for UWP apps does ***not*** include all the members of each type.

The [available string methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-2.1) are limited to only `AscW` at the moment.

However I would advise against using them anyway. Each of the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` methods you want just end up calling the `string.Length` and `string.SubString` anyway.  I used to miss these also, but most of the time what I really wanted was `string.StartsWith` and `string.EndsWith`.

Also note VB's `InStr` can be superseded by `string.IndexOf`

Comment: Have you tried that _in a UWP app_? Because I did, and it didn't work.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed in that case it's even more clear.  If the assembly is not even compatible, you won't (and you shouldn't anyway) be able to just paste in VB6 code and have it work.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed it indicates it's supported here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt185497.aspx

Comment: Perhaps someone could correct me, but AFAICT, in UWP `Left()`, `Right()`, `Mid()`, and `Len()` are not members of  `Microsoft.VisualBasic` _(although it **is** in other types of projects)_. I'm not even experienced with UWP but I just started an empty project to try it and it didn't work.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed looks like you are correct.  Despite referncing the assembly, the only available implemented methods are:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-2.1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Substring method.

Here are some examples:

```
Dim var1 as String="123456789"

Dim var2 as String

var2 = var1.Substring(3,3)  'returns "456"

var2 = var1.Substring(va1.Length - 3, 3) ' returns "789" equivalent of Right(3)

var2 = var1.Substring(3) 'returns "123" equivalent of Left(3).
```

Comment: I would appreciate if I know why I am downvoted? Very much beginner, trying to help out as much as I can. So can improve my answering techniques aand methods more technically! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not my DV but a link to an off site resource is not considered an answer.

Comment: @Plutonix: Oh! Thank for your kind reply. I would certainly take that into my consideration.